# jQuery never let img leave the edge of the containing div viewport

Tags: jquery, math

Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wmnWc/5/

Adjust the size of the viewport window to see what I'm trying to achieve.

As you can see in my code, I have setup the up the container height with a min-height value to the outer height of the form container. This because I would like to be able to scroll to the natural height of the form still leaving the background image visible still.

I also need the image to always stay at its natural proportions. As you can see this is what I tried to do.

Sample picture dimensions:

- Width: 2560px
- Height: 1709px

**Code**:

```
$(window).bind("resize.browsersize", function () {

    var viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
        viewportWidth = $(window).width(),
        loginHeight = $('#login').outerHeight(),
        containerHeight = $('.background-photo').height(),
        containerWidth = $('.background-photo').width(),
        ratioHeight = 1,
        ratioWidth = 1.497;

    $(".background-photo").css({
        'width': viewportWidth + 'px',
        'height': viewportHeight + 'px',
        'min-height': loginHeight + 'px'
    });

    if (containerHeight > containerWidth) {

        $(".background-photo img").css({
            'height': containerHeight + 'px',
            'width': containerHeight * ratioWidth + 'px',
            'max-width': containerHeight * ratioWidth + 'px'
        });

    } else if (containerWidth > containerHeight) {

        $(".background-photo img").css({
            'width': containerWidth + 'px',
            'height': 'auto',
            'max-width': containerWidth + 'px'
        });

    }

}).trigger("resize.browsersize");
```

Thanks in advance.

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not keep pretty simple ?

```
.background-photo { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:-1; overflow:hidden; }
img { max-width:100%; /*min-width:600px;*/ }

$(document).ready(function(){
    var imgRatio;
    $("img").load(function(){
        var $i = $(this);
        imgRatio = $i.width()/$i.height();
        var $w = $(window);
        $w.on("resize",function(){
            $i.css("min-width",$w.height() * imgRatio);
        }).resize();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wmnWc/10/

Comment: If you shrink of the width of the viewport - then you get a white space below the image, I need the image at all times to fill the containing div area but proportionately.

Comment: ok, add a bit of jquery to dinamically set min-width http://jsfiddle.net/wmnWc/10/

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you couldn't use `background-size: cover` ?

```
html { 
    background: url('http://www.motocomdigital.co.uk/login-background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/wmnWc/7/

Works in:

```
Safari 3+
Chrome Whatever+
IE 9+
Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)
Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)
```

Comment: This is what I originally did - but then it didnt work in older versions of IE - and it has to as my client uses it :-(

Comment: Then perhaps you could fallback on the jQuery solution in the case of older browsers? Perhaps this might help: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: r043v's solutions does not work - there's are white bar which appears below image, I need the image at all times to fill the containing div area but proportionately.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will help you:
I set a min-height which fills the browser window vertically, and set a 100% width which fills it horizontally. then set a min-width of the width of the image so that the image won't get smaller than it's size.this is easier and has no js.

```
.background-photo img {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: xxxxpx;/* image width */

    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```